# How to use string symbols like x,y as undefined variable in calculations in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I will try to explain what I want to do:

I will some polynomial approximation calculations in Python. And my aim is not to use numbers. I want to work with the symbols like x,y,c etc. But I couldn't find any way to use them in calculations. Simply I want to do that:

```
x=c1
y=c2
```

These x and y are my variables in the script.

```
x+y
print(x+y)
```

When I did `print(x+y)`, I want to see `c1+c2` on the screen. In the same way,

```
2*x
print(2*x)
```

When I did `print(2*x)`, I want to see `2c1` or `2*c1` on the screen. The same conditions should be valid for multiply and subtraction.

Can I do in Python and which library or function that I should use?

Comment: Do you want to see it as strings? if so you need to create class that can handle that.

Comment: SymPy https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/sympy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try sympy. It does what you want:

```
import sympy as sym
c1 = sym.Symbol('c1')
c2 = sym.Symbol('c2')
x=c1
y=c2

print(x+y)

print(2*x)
```

Output

```
c1 + c2
2*c1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `numpy.poly1d`, for representing above example you can define:

```
p = numpy.poly1d([2,0])
```